# Running shell script form Ruby on Rails on the Client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, server, client

I'd like to execute a shell script form my Rails app on the client.

In my case, I want to open a `.odt` file on the Client PC when he clicks on a link.

As for now, all I can do is run shell script on my server using `` e.g.
 `libreoffice path_to_my_odt_file` ``.
In this case, I'm opening my file using LivreOffice on the Server.

Is there a way to execute this code on my Client from Rails?

If I try to run my app as it is, when I call the action that calls my script, the file is opened on my Server.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think that you can run arbitrary commands on the client upon clicking a link, that would be a huge security risk. If you send the .odt - file to the client (i.e., the browser downloads the file), users can open the file pretty easily from there.

Comment: Yeah, it's impossible unless you had the client download and run a shell script.

Comment: I agree that it would be a major security flaw... I'm generating thie .odt file in my app and I'd like to show it on the Client (as I can't open this file on the browser). I was thinking on letting the Client download the file but that would cause some pain... I'd like to make it as automatic as possible, in the sense that it would not require furder user interaction. Any idea on how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in the comments, running arbitrary shell scripts on the client from the http server would be a huge security flaw.

As long as your Rails server provides a download link with [`send_data`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data)  (e.g. [`dynamically_generated_odt_file`](http://api.libreoffice.org/examples/cpp/DocumentLoader/test.odt)), the browser will ask if it should download the file or open it. If the user wants to avoid any extra interaction, there's the possibility to [tick](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file) :

> "Do this automatically for files like this from now on"

You might have to specify the MIME type, by adding

```
Mime::Type.register "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text", :odt
```

to `config/initializers/mime_types.rb`.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you very much.